# adding content to UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

I am trying to put a web view below an image in a scrollview. This code leads to a blank screen. I'm sure it's extremely simple (I'm a beginner), but could someone point me to my mistake?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = [self.detailItem title];
    //self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    //self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.detailItem imageURL]]]];

    self.imageView.image = image;
    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.detailItem url]]]];

    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.webView];
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 770, 320, 230);
    [self.webView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 770)];
    CGFloat scrollViewHeight = 1000.0f;
    /*
    for (UIView* view in scrollView.subviews)
    {
        NSLog(@"%f",view.frame.size.height);
        scrollViewHeight += view.frame.size.height;

    }
    */
    [scrollView setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(320, scrollViewHeight))];
    NSLog(@"%f", self.imageView.frame.size.height);
    NSLog(@"%f", self.webView.frame.size.height);

    [self configureView];
}
```

from the .h

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>{
    UIScrollView* scrollView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWebView *webView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *detailDescriptionLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView;
@end
```

Comment: in your loop where you add your subviews log your scrollviewHeight value to make sure that value is greater than 0

Comment: yeah it is zero. Any idea why that would be? The heights of the subviews are not zero.

Comment: Try to NSLog both scrollView.subviews and scrollViewHeight to make sure all works as it's supposed to that far.

Comment: I updated the code. It now gives me the scrollview, but the content is missing and the nslog output is zero for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are losing the original references to your ivar by reinitializing these values and you are not setting a frame so their height values are 0 which is why your scrollview isn't getting any larger:

```
self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
```

try changing them to only initialize if the value is nil

```
if(self.webView == nil){
    self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
}
if(self.imageView == nil){
    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

}

//set frames for subviews
UIImage *remoteLoadedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.detailItem imageURL]]];
[[self.imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,remoteLoadedImage.size.width, remoteLoadedImage.size.height)];
[self.imageView.image = remoteLoadedImage];
//i'm setting an arbitrary height and width
[self.webView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,self.imageView.frame.size.height+5, 320, 450)];
```

Comment: well, I can get the scrollview to appear by setting an arbitrary frame height, but the content (webview and imageview) does not appear. NSLog tells me that they still do not have a height even after I have set their frames.

Comment: ok, with the way that you've modifed your code, you need to check to see if your imageview and webview have in fact been initialized, then set the frames of those items before you add them to the scrollview.  that should allow you to iterate through scrollview subviews looking for the heights and getting the cumulative heights correctly.

Comment: it works! is there a way to get the length of the webpage before I set up the frames?

Comment: Perhaps, if you know the size of the content you expect to load in the webpage then you can approximate the size.

Answer (score 0):

In the given code, you don't initialize self.scrollView.

Comment: Are things added through interface builder already initialized? In any case, initializing it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Yes they are. Did you connect the outlet?